# icontact subscription/unsubscription using API

Tags: php, icontact

I am using PHP icontact API 2.2.
I faced an issue with subscription and unsubscription of contact to specific list using this API.
I can subscribe properly  but once i un-subscribe a contact then i can't subscribe it again.

I am using the code below

```
For subscription
$oiContact->subscribeContactToList($contact_id , $list_id ,'normal' );

for unsubscription
$oiContact->subscribeContactToList($contact_id , $list_id ,'unsubscribed' );
```

I also checked this 
http://developer.icontact.com/documentation/subscriptions/

Can any one help me to solve this ? they mentioned in this link

```
https://app.sandbox.icontact.com/icp/a/{accountId}/c/{clientFolderId}/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}
```

Using this method i wrote a function like

```
public function subscriptionStatus($subscriptionId,$sStatus = 'normal') {
        // Valid statuses
        $aValidStatuses = array('normal', 'pending', 'unsubscribed');
        // Setup the subscription and make the call
        $aSubscriptions = $this->makeCall("/a/{$this->setAccountId()}/c/{$this->setClientFolderId()}/subscriptions/{$subscriptionId}", 'POST', 

            array('status'    => $sStatus), 'subscriptions');
        // Return the subscription
        return $aSubscriptions;
    }
```

But it will return "error:Forbidden"

Comment: nothing added in error_log it return  like this array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "Forbidden"
}
string(19) "{"status":"normal"}"
string(24) "{"errors":["Forbidden"]}"

Comment: it means "You are logged in, but do not have permission to perform that action" from iContact http://developer.icontact.com/documentation/http-status-codes/

Comment: thanks for your response .ok , i saw the error codes but i can do all other action like adding new contact etc ..even unsubscription ?